# How to write a method that counts the most common substring in a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this program with a class DNA. The program counts the most frequent k-mer in a string. So, it is looking for the most common substring in a string with a length of k.

An example would be creating a dna1 object with a string of AACCAATCCG. The count k-mer method will look for a subtring with a length of k and output the most common answer. So, if we set k = 1 then 'A' and 'C' will be the most occurrence in the string because it appears four times. See example below:

```
 dna1 = DNA.new('AACCAATCCG')
=> AACCAATCCG
>> dna1.count_kmer(1)
=> [#<Set: {"A", "C"}>, 4]
>> dna1.count_kmer(2)
=> [#<Set: {"AA", "CC"}>, 2]
```

Here is my DNA class :

```
   class DNA
      def initialize (nucleotide)
        @nucleotide = nucleotide
      end
      def length
        @nucleotide.length
      end   
      protected
 attr_reader :nucleotide
end
```

Here is my count kmer method that I am trying to implement:

```
# I have k as my only parameter because I want to pass the nucleotide string in the method
def count_kmer(k)

# I created an array as it seems like a good way to split up the nucleotide string.
  counts = []

  #this tries to count how many kmers of length k there are
  num_kmers = self.nucleotide.length- k + 1

  #this should try and look over the kmer start positions
  for i in num_kmers

    #Slice the string, so that way we can get the kmer
    kmer = self.nucleotide.split('')
  end

  #add kmer if its not present
  if !kmer = counts
    counts[kmer] = 0

    #increment the count for kmer
    counts[kmer] +=1 
  end

  #return the final count
return counts
end

#end dna class
end
```

I'm not sure where my method went wrong.

Comment: Seems like there is even a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer#Ruby) for it? ;)
Apart from that, it looks in your implementation, you're splitting the nucleotide into its characters a couple of times but doing nothing with the result. I.e. that first `for` loop is somewhat pointless. Also, `counts` should probably be a `Hash`, not an array. And to check whether it's present you can use `counts.key?(kmer)` or alternatively `counts[kmer] ||= 0`. Better start once again with pseudo-code and put it into real code afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
def most_frequent_substrings(str, k)
  (0..str.size-k).each_with_object({}) do |i,h|
    b = [] 
    str[i..-1].scan(Regexp.new str[i,k]) { b << Regexp.last_match.begin(0) + i }
    (h[b.size] ||= []) << b
  end.max_by(&:first).last.each_with_object({}) { |a,h| h[str[a.first,k]] = a } 
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "ABBABABBABCATSABBABB"
most_frequent_substrings(str, 4)
  #=> {"ABBA"=>[0, 5, 14], "BBAB"=>[1, 6, 15]}
```

This shows that the most frequently-occurring 4-character substring of `str`appears 3 times. There are two such substrings: "ABBA" and "BBAB". "ABBA" begins at offsets (into `str`) 0, 5 and 14, "BBAB" substrings begin at offsets 1, 6 and 15.

**Explanation**

For the example above the steps are as follows.

```
k = 4
n = str.size - k
  #=> 20 - 4 => 16
e = (0..n).each_with_object([])
  #<Enumerator: 0..16:each_with_object([])>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[0, []], [1, []], [2, []], [3, []], [4, []], [5, []], [6, []], [7, []], [8, []],
 #     [9, []], [10, []], [11, []], [12, []], [13, []], [14, []], [15, []], [16, []]]
```

Note the empty array contained in each element will be modified as the array is built. Continuing, the first element of `e` is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned using *parallel assignment*:

```
i,a = e.next
  #=> [0, []] 
i #=> 0 
a #=> []
```

We are now considering the substring of size 4 that begins at `str` offset `i #=> 0`, which is seen to be "ABBA". Now the block calculation is performed.

```
b = []
r = Regexp.new str[i,k]
  #=> Regexp.new str[0,4]
  #=> Regexp.new "ABBA"
  #=> /ABAB/
str[i..-1].scan(r) { b << Regexp.last_match.begin(0) + i }
  #=> "ABBABABBABCATSABBABB".scan(r) { b << Regexp.last_match.begin(0) + i } 
b #=> [0, 5, 14]
```

We next have

```
(h[b.size] ||= []) << b
```

which becomes

```
(h[b.size] = h[b.size] || []) << b
  #=> (h[3] = h[3] || []) <<  [0, 5, 14]
```

Since `h` has no key `3`, `h[3]` on the right side equals `nil`. Continuing,

```
  #=> (h[3] = nil || []) <<  [0, 5, 14]
  #=> (h[3] = []) <<  [0, 5, 14]
h #=> { 3=>[[0, 5, 14]] }
```

Notice that we throw away `scan`'s return value. All we need is `b`

This tells us the "ABBA" appears thrice in `str`, beginning at offsets 0, 5 and 14.

Now observe

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[0, [[0, 5, 14]]],  [1, [[0, 5, 14]]],  [2, [[0, 5, 14]]],
  #    ...
  #    [16, [[0, 5, 14]]]]
```

After all elements of `e` have been passed to the block, the block returns

```
h #=> {3=>[[0, 5, 14], [1, 6, 15]],
  #    1=>[[2], [3], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16]],
  #    2=>[[4, 16], [5, 14], [6, 15]]}
```

Consider substrings that appear just once: `h[1]`. One of those is `[2]`. This pertains to the 4-character substring beginning at `str` offset `2`:

```
str[2,4]
  #=> "BABA"
```

That is found to be the only instance of that substring. Similarly, among the substrings that appear twice is `str[4,4] = str[16,4] #=> "BABB", given by h[2][0] #=>  [4, 16]`.

Next we determine the greatest frequency of a substring of length 4:

```
c = h.max_by(&:first)
  #=> [3, [[0, 5, 14], [1, 6, 15]]]
```

(which could also be written `c = h.max_by { |k,_| k }`).

```
d = c.last
  #=> [[0, 5, 14], [1, 6, 15]]
```

For convenience, convert `d` to a hash:

```
d.each_with_object({}) { |a,h| h[str[a.first,k]] = a }
  #=> {"ABBA"=>[0, 5, 14], "BBAB"=>[1, 6, 15]}
```

and return that hash from the method.

There is one detail that deserves mention. It is possible that `d` will contain two or more arrays that reference the same substring, in which case the value of the associated key (the substring) will equal the last of those arrays. Here's a simple example.

```
str = "AAA"
k = 2
```

In this case the array `d` above will equal

```
d = [[0], [1]]
```

Both of these reference `str[0,2] #=> str[1,2] #=> "AA"`. In building the hash the first is overwritten by the second:

```
d.each_with_object({}) { |a,h| h[str[a.first,k]] = a }
  #=> {"AA"=>[1]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
  require 'set'

  def count_kmer(k)
    max_kmers = kmers(k)
                    .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |value, count| count[value] += 1 }
                    .group_by { |_,v| v }
                    .max
    [Set.new(max_kmers[1].map { |e| e[0] }), max_kmers[0]]
  end

  def kmers(k)
    nucleotide.chars.each_cons(k).map(&:join)
  end
```

EDIT: Here's the full text of the class:

```
require 'set'

class DNA
  def initialize (nucleotide)
    @nucleotide = nucleotide
  end

  def length
    @nucleotide.length
  end

  def count_kmer(k)
    max_kmers = kmers(k)
                    .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |value, count| count[value] += 1 }
                    .group_by { |_,v| v }
                    .max
    [Set.new(max_kmers[1].map { |e| e[0] }), max_kmers[0]]
  end

  def kmers(k)
    nucleotide.chars.each_cons(k).map(&:join)
  end

  protected
  attr_reader :nucleotide
end
```

This produces the following output, using Ruby 2.2.1, using the class and method you specified:

```
>> dna1 = DNA.new('AACCAATCCG')
=> #<DNA:0x007fe15205bc30 @nucleotide="AACCAATCCG">
>> dna1.count_kmer(1)
=> [#<Set: {"A", "C"}>, 4]
>> dna1.count_kmer(2)
=> [#<Set: {"AA", "CC"}>, 2]
```

As a bonus, you can also do:

```
>> dna1.kmers(2)
=> ["AA", "AC", "CC", "CA", "AA", "AT", "TC", "CC", "CG"]
```

Comment: running dna1.count_kmer(2) gives me this output: 
`#<Set:0x007fb9ca1141b8>
2` I was trying to get something like this  `[#<Set: {"A", "C"}>, 4]`

Comment: The code produces exactly what you wanted on my end. You may need to add the line `require 'set'`, which I had not shown initially.